# Umbraco: How to find unpublished node

Tags: umbraco

I have created an Umbraco package and, after installation, I need to ask the user for information that I need to place in one of the content nodes installed.

There's one thing stopping me from completing this project. The content node in question installed with my package is `unpublished`. How do I find the node?

I thought of republishing the whole site but the site owner might have content that he doesn't wish to publish.

As of writing this question, I also thought of creating the nodes myself.

How to achieve any of this?

Comment: Do you know the Id of the node?

Comment: No, that's why I couldn't find the node. I ended up creating the nodes but it would be useful to be able to access unpublish nodes. If the nodes were too complex this might have become a bigger issue than it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class Document will let you see unpublish content. The behavior is the same as the Node class but with published and unpublished nodes.

Comment: Thanks Stephane. I can't go back now and test it as I have found another solution and need to move forward, but I'll trust you as it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the nodes programatically instead of just adding them as content and then, kowing the ids, it was possible to publish them right away.